# Is it possible to use Xcode cloud to build ios apps on older(unsupported) mac os versions?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

On older macos versions(pre MacOS Catalina) I can not build(archive etc...) ios apps. Once a build is made using a latest version of Xcode on another device and deployed to testflight, is it somehow possible to use Xcode Cloud to build from the unsupported version on an old mac/macbook?